# DCOS cluster scaling

Tags: apache-spark, scaling, mesosphere, dcos

I have a DCOS cluster with 3 agent nodes; I have few services like spark running on DCOS.

> 1. If i scale my DCOS cluster, do i need to scale my spark as well
>      (because if i add a 4th node to DCOS cluster and when i run a spark
>      job, master may allocate resources for the spark job to be run on the
>      4th node where spark is not installed and hence it will fail)?

In my observation, i found that the jobs are being submitted to any node that Mesos master sees.

> 2. Is there a way where i can specify Spark job not run on certain nodes?

Comment: As no explanation for the downvote was supplied, I'm upvoting back to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not by default, so you will have to scale Spark. In this context by scale I refer to adding more executors. There is no need to perform any additional package installs to support this.

Dynamic allocation may help, but I've not used it:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html#dynamic-resource-allocation-with-mesos

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#dynamic-resource-allocation

2. You can control where jobs run in Marathon, but to my knowledge not Spark, via DCOS. I think you will be able to achieve it in the underlying Mesos configuration, but it's not recommended.  You can create multiple Spark 'clusters' within one DCOS cluster and choose which spark instance to submit to:

> To install mutiple instances of the DC/OS Spark package, set each
>   service.name to a unique name (e.g.: “spark-dev”) in your JSON
>   configuration file during installation:

```
{
  "service": {
    "name": "spark-dev"
  }
}
```

> To use a specific Spark instance from the DC/OS Spark CLI:

`$ dcos config set spark.app_id <service.name>`

https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.8/usage/service-guides/spark/install/

Comment: On 1 i would expect DCOS to automatically understand where Spark is installed and assign resources accordingly. Otherwise, if i have 500 nodes DCOS cluster, i may have to install Spark in each and every node which is not good. Do you think service discovery would help in this case?

Comment: You don't need to install Spark manually on each node if you are using DCOS, you install the Spark 'package' once using the DCOS CLI which takes care of the manual lifting. Apologies if I mislead you there. The Spark distro is handled by the docker image. At least on a default DCOS install it does.

Comment: If i install Spark package on DC/OS, i have seen that it gets installed on the nodes in the cluster based on the number of instances required. Spark would not be installed on all nodes i.e. if you have 100 nodes in the cluster and if i install spark with only 5 instances, then it would install only on a maximum of 5 machines. Now the problem is that when the Spark Job gets submitted, then Mesos allocates resources to nodes where Spark is not installed. Hence it fails. I have seen this situation and i was expecting DC/OS to allocate resource only on the nodes where Spark is installed. Thoughts?

Comment: It's not behaviour I have observed and seems contrary to my experience of DCOS. AFAIK DCOS pulls a docker image containing Spark distro on job submit, Spark is never installed on nodes as you would in standalone. How are you submitting your Spark job - via DCOS CLI or some other mechanism?  Have I grossly misunderstood the situation somewhere?

Comment: Spark job is run with the "dcos spark run" command. Spark is never installed? So when the Spark package is installed, whats that tasks running that i see on DC/OS UI, Marathon UI, Mesos UI? i see every UI and when i run the job, i see the driver running on one agent node and the tasks of the job running on the other nodes.

Comment: It is running inside docker containers pulled from mesosphere docker hub https://hub.docker.com/r/mesosphere/spark/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135700/discussion-between-learninghuman-and-imdarreng).